# could not able to automate

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

it is  login automation upon providing correct credentials user should logged in but even though I am providing correct credentials during test automation I am not able to proceed to next window.

when I talked to developer's team they told me they used telerik's control
while manual testing works good automation is stuck.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"uxUserName\"]")).sendKeys("medward");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"uxPasswordMask\"]")).sendKeys("ASas!@12");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"uxLogin_input\"]")).click();
```

showing no error messages but expected result is also not performed

Comment: We need more info than "unable to proceed..."  Are you getting an error message?  Are any of the two fields being populated?.  Two tips: first it makes it more readable if you use a single quote (') instead of slash-quote (\") in your xpaths, and second, since you are using the ID attribute, it's better to just use `By.id(...`

Comment: you need wait before click to `uxLogin_input` => the telerik validation is not finish

Comment: no error message